Saving state of the cropped image to make further operations on that image
I am creating an image editing library. I have several methods like crop(), rotate(), flipX() and so on. I am using DOMMatrix and canvas for my image editing library.
I have my crop function which takes cropping dimensions from the cropper box.
My image is getting cropped properly when my image is at 0 degree.
I am facing 2 problems:

After cropping when I am rotating the image, my image is getting reset to original dimensions and then it is getting rotated.
After rotation, if I am cropping the image then the cropped image is smaller than the expected image. (This may be due to resizing of the canvas due to rotation...)

  private cropImage() {
    this.saveState();
    const {
      offsetLeft: cropX,
      offsetTop: cropY,
      clientWidth: cropWidth,
      clientHeight: cropHeight,
    } = this.cropperBox;
    const scaleX = this.canvas.width / this.canvas.clientWidth;
    const scaleY = this.canvas.height / this.canvas.clientHeight;
    const realCropX = cropX * scaleX;
    const realCropY = cropY * scaleY;
    const realCropWidth = cropWidth * scaleX;
    const realCropHeight = cropHeight * scaleY;

    console.log(this.cropperBox.offsetLeft, this.cropperBox.offsetHeight, this.cropperBox.clientHeight, this.cropperBox.clientWidth);

    this.croppedImageData = this.context.getImageData(
      realCropX,
      realCropY,
      realCropWidth,
      realCropHeight
    );
    this.canvas.width = realCropWidth;
    this.canvas.height = realCropHeight;
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.resetTransform()
    this.context.putImageData(this.croppedImageData, 0, 0);
    this.croppedWidth = realCropWidth;
    this.croppedHeight = realCropHeight;  
    this.transformMatrix = this.context.getTransform()
    this.context.setTransform(this.transformMatrix)  
  }

  public rotate(angle: number) {
    this.saveState();
    this.currentRotation += angle;

    const angle_in_radians = this.currentRotation * (Math.PI / 180);

    const newWidth =
      Math.abs(Math.cos(angle_in_radians) * this.img.width) +
      Math.abs(Math.sin(angle_in_radians) * this.img.height);
    const newHeight =
      Math.abs(Math.sin(angle_in_radians) * this.img.width) +
      Math.abs(Math.cos(angle_in_radians) * this.img.height);
    this.canvas.width = newWidth;
    this.canvas.height = newHeight;
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.transformMatrix = this.context.getTransform();
    const canvasCentreX = this.canvas.width / 2;
    const canvasCentreY = this.canvas.height / 2;
    this.transformMatrix.translateSelf(canvasCentreX, canvasCentreY);
    this.transformMatrix.rotateSelf(this.currentRotation);
    if (this.currentFlipX) {
      this.transformMatrix.scaleSelf(-1, 1);
    }
    if (this.currentFlipY) {
      this.transformMatrix.scaleSelf(1, -1);
    }
    this.transformMatrix.translateSelf(
      -this.img.width / 2,
      -this.img.height / 2
    );
    this.context.setTransform(this.transformMatrix);
    this.context.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);

  }

